# Simple p:inputText in p:dialog not setting value in @Named Bean

Tags: primefaces, dialog

I am using primefaces 5.1 and still facing problem with p:dialog and p:inputText within that dialog.

Here is the .xhtml content

```
    <ui:define name="content">

    <f:metadata> <f:viewAction action="#{vLoginController.initSetup}" /> </f:metadata>

    <h:form id="vhome" prependId="false">

        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p:commandButton value="Place Order" action="#{vLoginController.placeOrderHomePage}"
                                    update="logindialog, signupdialog"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <p:dialog id="logindialog" header="Login / Sign up" visible="#{vLoginController.loginDialog}"
                    draggable="false" resizable="false" modal="true">

            <p:messages autoUpdate="true"/>

            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                <h:outputLabel for="inuserid" value="EmailID:" />
                <p:inputText id="inuserid" size="40" value="#{vLoginController.user.userId}" />

                <h:outputLabel for="inpassword" value="Password:" />
                <p:password id="inpassword" size="20" value="#{vLoginController.user.password}" />

                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton value="Login" process="@form" action="#{vLoginController.validateLogin}" update="logindialog"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Sign up" action="#{vLoginController.showSignup}" update="logindialog, signupdialog"/>
                </f:facet>
            </h:panelGrid>

        </p:dialog>

        <p:dialog id="signupdialog" header="Sign up / Login" visible="#{vLoginController.signupDialog}"
                    draggable="false" resizable="false" modal="true">

                <p:outputLabel>Test</p:outputLabel>
        </p:dialog>

    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

Here is the supporting Bean

```
@Named
@SessionScoped

public class VLoginController extends BaseController implements Serializable {

private VUser user;

public VLoginController() {

}

public void placeOrderHomePage() {

    loginDialog = true;
    signupDialog = false;

}

public String validateLogin() {

    // Validate the screen fields
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage();
    msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if (user.getUserId() == null || user.getPassword() == null) {

        msg.setSummary("Enter User ID and Password");
        context.addMessage("screenvalidation", msg);

        return null;
    }

}

}


public class VUser implements Serializable {

public VUser() {
}

private int userSeq;
private String userId;
private String userType;
private String password;
private String salt;
private int active;

}
```

The userID and password in the user object are always null. Have gone through various forums content and tried like adding outputpanel around them etc., but none works. Have kept the code very similar to what the primefaces showcase says, still doesn't work.

Any solution please.. Please note that there is no problem in showing or hiding the dialog boxes, those logic works perfect. I just need to get the values entered by the user in the dialog fields to the bean..

Comment: check for nested forms.

Comment: OT: Don't use prependId="false". Search Stackoverflow on why

Comment: Removed prependId="false" and it works like a charm, able to get the values in the bean. Thank you..